# Momentjs - Add days with specific time

Tags: momentjs

I'm using momentjs to calculate certain dates. For example:

```
moment().add(7, 'days');
```

This returns date in 7 days in same time like now:
**Thu May 21 2020 12:06:35 GMT+0200**.

What is the function for adding days but in specific time like:
**Thu May 21 2020 17:00:00 GMT+0200**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
 moment({ hour: 17 }).add(7, 'd')
```

This ads exactly 7 days to today in 17:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the `add()` to get add hours,minutes,seconds.

```js
console.log('Current time: ', moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
var start_time = moment()
  .add(1, "days")
  .add(4, "hours")
  .add(21, "seconds");
console.log('modified time: ', start_time.format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But, how can I add specific time, like from your example 15-05-2020 17:00:00,
So to add not in "4" hours, but specific time?

Comment: I dont think there is a function. You might wanna parse your time to hours , minutes and seconds and then chain add functions

Comment: I found a solution :) you can check it. Thanks!